# How bind POST data to object can save to Doctrine

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

How bind POST data to object can save or edit to Doctrine.

I use Doctrine with annotation entities. I don't figure out as bind array data to entities .

I read about Symfony's components as standalone, too.

Example :

```
$_POST # form data , array

# this is how doctrine save object
$product = new Product();
$product->setName('product1');
$entityManager->persist($product);
$entityManager->flush();
```

I want  `$product = $helper->convert($_POST, ...) # return product object`
then i can persist $product to $entityManager.

Comment: We need more information if you want us to help you. Some code, some configuration file, etc ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you how to handle forms:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

To put data on an Entitiy user the setters.

```
$entity->setName('Mitchel');
```

If you want to put a post on a entity you have to create a function like this:

```
    public function setAttributes( array $values )
    {
        foreach( $values as $attribute => $value ) {
            $dateEng = "/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$/";
            $dateNl  = "/^([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})$/";
            if( preg_match ($dateEng, $value) OR preg_match ($dateNl, $value) ){
                $value = date_create( $value );
            }

            if(is_string( $value )){
                if(preg_match( '/^\d+$/', $value )){
                    $value = (int) $value;
                }
            }

            $this->{'set' . ucfirst( $attribute )}( $value );
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

This works for me =)
And if I find a case who doesn't works I just add some code.

Comment: ok , thanks a lot. I read Symfony Form components . but it is too complicated .. I think write a function like yours , but don't know if it suits in a many case ( security or .. ).

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to go this way, you should use **ClassMetadata** class to determine field names first or you will get "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method ..." when user post extra data.

Something like this:

```
<?php 
function setAttributes($values) {
$cm = new ClassMetadata(__CLASS__);
foreach ($cm->getFieldNames() as $field) { 
  if (array_key_exists($values, $field))
    $this->{'set' . ucfirst( $attribute )}( $value );
// ...
```

**But I would strongly recommend you to learn Form component**. It took me just one day to start and about a week to make complicate forms.